# Column is either not in any table in the FROM list Java database searching

Tags: java, sql, database

I'm working on a database program in Java and I've run into a problem with it telling me that what I'm searching for is not located in the table.

```
public static void displayRecord(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException
{
    String assignment = rs.getString("assignment");
    int grade = rs.getInt("grade");
    System.out.println(assignment + " | " + grade + "\n");
}

public void findGrade(String assignment){

    String assignString;
    int gradeInt;

    try{
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception err){
        System.err.println("Unable to load the embedded driver.");
        err.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }
    Connection connected = null;

    try{

        int ble = 25;
        connected = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + databaseName);

        Statement statement = connected.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = null;

        rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT assignment, grade FROM student WHERE assignment = " + assignment);

        if(rs == null ) {
            System.out.println("Assignment not found!");
        }
        else {
            displayRecord(rs);
        }

        rs.close();

        connected.close();


    }

    catch (SQLException err){
        System.err.println("SQL error.");
        err.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

It ends up giving me the following error

> SQL error.
>   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Column 'ASSIGNMENT1' is either not in any table in the FROM list or appears within a join specification and is outside the scope of the join specification or appears in a HAVING clause and is not in the GROUP BY list. If this is a CREATE or ALTER TABLE  statement then 'ASSIGNMENT1' is not a column in the target table.
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.ConnectionChild.handleException(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
>       at Student.findGrade(Student.java:153)
>       at GradeBookTester.main(GradeBookTester.java:17)

I am unsure why it is giving me the error as is exist in my database.

I'll give the code for the tester and database creator itself to see if mistakes are made there but it all seems pretty solid.

DataBase:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class CreateGradeBook{

private static final String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
private static final String protocol = "jdbc:derby:";

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try{
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        System.out.println("Loaded the embedded driver.");
    }
    catch (Exception err){
        System.err.println("Unable to load the embedded driver.");
        err.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String dbName = "GradeBook";
    Connection connected = null;

    try{
        System.out.println("connecting to and creating the database...");
        connected = DriverManager.getConnection(protocol + dbName + ";create=true");
        System.out.println("database created.");

        Statement statement = connected.createStatement();

        statement.execute("CREATE TABLE student" + "(student_name varchar(50), student_id int, assignment varchar(80), grade int)");
        System.out.println("created Student table.");


        connected.close();
    }

    catch (SQLException err){
        System.err.println("SQL error.");
        err.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

and here is the code for the tester

```
public class GradeBookTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student bob = new Student();

    bob.setStudentName("Bob");
    bob.setStudnetID(12345);

    bob.addGrade("ASSIGNMENT1", 100);
    bob.addGrade("assignment2", 50);
    bob.addGrade("assignment3", 25);
    bob.addGrade("assignment4", 100);

    bob.displayGrades();

    bob.findGrade("ASSIGNMENT1");
}

}
```

Comment: your question preparation is so good but never use explicit sqls in your codes against sql-injection danger. Use procedure calls instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention the search string with quotes like below,

```
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT assignment, grade FROM student WHERE assignment = '" + assignment + "'");
```

The problem is your query got interpreted like below,

> SELECT assignment, grade FROM student WHERE assignment=**ASSIGNMENT1**

rather than

> SELECT assignment, grade FROM student WHERE assignment = **'ASSIGNMENT1'**

making the query interpreter to considering it as a column rather than value

Comment: Ah okie dokie, yeah that makes a lot of sense cant believed i missed that. Thank you very much!